# jQuery UI datepicker onSelectAfter

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

how can i execute a function after a date was selected? onSelect seems to fire before. i want to check if the selected date has a particular class.

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                if($('.ui-state-active').parent().hasClass('express')){
                    console.log('express click');
                }else{
                    console.log('no express click');
                }
            }
```

this doesn't work. Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please:

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
var day  = inst.selectedDay,
                mon  = inst.selectedMonth,
                year = inst.selectedYear;

var el = $(inst.dpDiv).find('[data-year="'+year+'"][data-month="'+mon+'"]').filter(function() {
                return $(this).find('a').text().trim() == day;
            });

           if ( el.parent().hasClass('express')){
                  console.log('express click');
            }else{
                console.log('no express click');
            }            
}
```

Comment: Works! Thank you so much, you made my day!